# What is the OracleCoherence library for .Net Core?

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle-coherence

There is OracleCoherence.dll v12.2.1.3 for .Net Framework.
What is the equivalent OracleCoherence package for target framework .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

This has been taken into consideration by the team.
https://github.com/oracle/coherence-dotnet-extend-client/issues/1